How to compare cells data with columns using python
I have an excel with some data like below imageexcel data
If you compare column A WITH column C(A4 present in C18 and A5 present in C17) so these two will true and other is false, how to write code in python
I can see only row comparison, now looking for cell to column comparison like(A1 has to compare column C and repeate this by increasing A2, A3.....)

Use openpyxl in pyhton with excel formula.
To check column A value exists in column C table, you can use COUNTIF function to column B. i.e.
=COUNTIF(C$3:C$18,A3)>0

In python use for loop to iterate through rows
for row_num in range(3, 12+1):
    sheet['B{}'.format(row_num)] = '=COUNTIF(C$3:C$18,A{})>0'.format(row_num)


for row_num in range(3, 12+1):
sheet['B{}'.format(row_num)] = '=COUNTIF(C$3:C$18,A{})>0'.format(row_num) - could you please explain what is 3 and 12+1, C$3:C$18 and how to update the comparison result to other column(true or false)

is there any error below code: sheet['D{}'.format(3,12+1)] = '=COUNTIF(F$3:sheet.max_row,B{})>0'.format(row_num),'=COUNTIF(G$3:sheet.max_row,C{})>0'.format(row_num)
